# Typescript decorator mess

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, nestjs

Is there a way to solve massive decorator use inside classes?

Here's an example of a **single** property of a class in my NestJS app, with an **incomplete swagger documentation** decorator:

```js
  @ApiModelProperty({
    description: 'description',
  })
  @Expose()
  @MaxLength(100, { message: 'message' })
  @IsString({ message: 'message' })
  @ValidateIf(address=> address.id !== null)
  @NotEquals(undefined, { message: 'message' })
  address: string;
```

This gets huge and ugly in no time. Any way to make the code look cleaner, defining the decorators in another file, maybe?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by `solve`?

Comment: If a library decides to use decorators it uses decorators ... not really much can be done about it .. maybe define some compound decorators..

Comment: @Olian04 By solve i mean not having so much lines of decorations in one single file, they make code hard to read and you have different types of them mixed (i.e. validation and documentation). Example, using express-validator you sometimes got a huge chained validation, but thanks to how the router uses middleware, you could remove that from your file into another one, then importing it as an array of validation middlewares. That makes code super clean.But I have little experience using decorators and i wanted to know if there is a way to have similar results.

Comment: A couple of things to take a look into, see if you can cut down on the number of decorators you are using. You have a `@ValidateIf(address => address.id !== null)` but your `address` type is `string` which doesn't have an id field. `@Expose()` is only needed if you want to expose the field of the class, but have no real validations to run against it, so there's an extraneous decorator. I'm pretty sure you can get rid of the `@NotEquals()` possibly by options in the `@IsString()` decorator or by using the `@Length()` decorator to combine your max and min length (1,100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure for how long this has existed under nestjs/common library, but I stumbled with this issue and in case someone else stumbles with this. After requesting help on their official discord, [jmcdo29](https://github.com/jmcdo29) suggested https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition which seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

Decorators are regular typescript functions. You can try to compose multiple decorators into a single one. For exemple, you could mix the validation ones into a single decorator, like this:

```
function apiStringField(maxLength: number, message: string, description?: string) {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) { 
      ApiModelProperty()(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
      Expose()(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
      MaxLength(maxLength, { message })(target, propertyKey, descriptor) 
      IsString({ message })(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
      NotEquals(undefined, { message })(target, propertyKey, descriptor) 
  }
}
```

And, use it like this (after importing it):

```
@apiStringField(100, 'message', 'description')
address: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

This good nestjs util helped in my case, maybe it helps you:

```
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

expose function ComposedDecorator(options: any) {
  return applyDecorators(
    Decorator1(),
    Decorator2(),
    AnotherDecoratorYouWant(),
  )
}
```

And then:

```
@ComposedDecorator(options)
// methodOrClassOrProperty
```